# white dotted lines in backbuttons / Appbars - Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

How to avoid the white dotted line around the backbutton (or other controls) which occur randomly in Windows Store App development ?

Comment: The dotted lines are not random. That is Windows telling the user that the control has focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your answer does solve your problem, it does so with side effects. Chances are if your are developing for Windows 8 you want to consider the full experience for your users, and removing an item that can be focused and interacted with from the tab sequence makes it impossible to navigate to via keyboard (without some sort of focus hack). Instead, if you don't desire the traditional focus lines, create a [Control Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465374.aspx) for your button. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check as to which control is getting affected by this dotted line. Now switch to the xaml side and set the "**IsTabStop**" property to "**false**" for the affected control. It is said that the white dotted line is due to undesired focus falling on some controls during an event.